# How to export a Java desktop app into a executable jar that uses some project files

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export

I have a Java desktop app with gui.My app is using some xml files from the "export" folder. When I export the app into a runnable jar file, the app is not working properly, because the jar does not contain this xml files, or the path to the files is wrong.

Is there any possibility to export a Java app into an executable jar file from eclipse and to tell somehow to include an additional folder, with the same structure?

[image]

### More information

My project is using some xml files, organized in the following hierarchy:

templates -> HASH CODE fgrtsgdtagsdnjf -> test -> document.xml
templates -> HASH CODE sgdtfhfnjnjcnjc -> test -> document.xml

When I export my project into an executable jar file I don't know how to specify to my app to use that files. I have FileNotFoundException.

So far, I succeed during export into an executable jar file to export that folders with XML files as well. So the files exists in the jar archive. but I do not how to indicate to use them in my project?

Comment: export has only xml files?

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you get FileNotFoundException, I assume you are trying to use File, FileStream, FileReader or similar; you can't use those, you need to use class.getResourceAsStream() (search first in the the same directory as the class) or class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream() or getSystemResourceAsStream().

Eclipse packages the contents of the source folders (i.e. src, export and test) in the root of the JAR, so if you have "export/document.xml" you'd use 'MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("document.xml")'. And remember to close the stream.

Comment: Thanks, I have already solved it, and you are right. I used something like this: MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/myPackage/templates/"+templateKey+ "myDocument.xml");

Answer (score 0):

> My app is using some xml files from the "export" folder.

If export folder has only required xml files, then just move it inside src folder. It would be automatically included once you Export as Executable Jar

Another option is to right click the folder and select Build Path, experimenting with it might help.

> Is there any possibility to export a java app into an executable jar file from eclipse and to tell somehow to include an additional folder, with the same structure?

When you export as executable jar there is an option to save scenario as Ant script. Later you can modify it and Run as -> Ant